# error : Project "" does not contain any configuration

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml, c++-winrt

I have created a simple static library using Blank app template from this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CppWinRTTeam.cppwinrt101804264

[image]

I have customized the project a bit.
I have removed configuration and added following code

```
<Lib>
      <AdditionalOptions Condition="'$(Platform)'=='Win32'">/MACHINE:x86</AdditionalOptions>
      <AdditionalOptions Condition="'$(Platform)'!='Win32'">/MACHINE:$(Platform)</AdditionalOptions>
</Lib>
```

But I am getting the error
'Project "" does not contain any configuration.'

I do not get this error when I add the same vcxproj code in another solution. the project is the same in both cases, just adding it in another solution does not give me this error.
Here is my simple project - https://github.com/rajendrasp/WinrtDemo
Any idea what is wrong with this project?

Comment: The "Blank App" template does not create a static library. If your project generates one you have certainly made more changes than *"a bit"*. Please explain what you have done and show a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: @IInspectable I tried with the Static Library template as well. You are right, I have changed the vcxproj file a lot. So it does not matter which template I start with. I have to customize it. I have explained what I have done by editing original question. And the github repo is the minimal reproducible example. It is just project created from the template and edited the vcxproj file nothing else added.

Comment: This is neither a [mcve] nor is it part of the question. And it's entirely unclear what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: It is minimal. It is a simple project created from template, nothing more. And I kept it in a github because I cannot put all of code here in question. And problem I am trying to solve is how to get rid of this error for the given project?

Comment: If you are having difficulty posting your [mcve] here, then chances are that it's not minimal. You're going to have to try harder if you want this resolved. Regardless, it's still unclear what problem you hope to solve by turning a project that generates a UWP package into a static library. That doesn't make much sense.